# My html code is working fine, but validator gives me parse-error. I tried removing tags, but not working. i have style.css file, and bootstrap link

Tags: html, css, parse-error

[parse-error][1]

my html code is having trouble passing Markup validator.
returning parse-error.

I tried removing every tags, but its not working.

I need to have no errors on validator for cs50 course.

```
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>START of >>> the thing</title>
    <nav class="nav fs-3" style="width: 100%; padding: 3%; background-color: #ffffff;">
        <a class="nav-link" href="../index.html">MUNKHSULD. B</a>
        <a class="nav-link center" aria-current="page" href="../about.html">ABOUT</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="../contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="../wiki.html">WIKI</a>
    </nav>
</head>

<body class='back'>
    <h1 class='title'>Hello, this is my home page, which is written on CSS, HTML and JAVASCRIPT.</h1>
    <p class='para'>I have just started coding through CS50, couple months ago.</p>
    <p class='para'>So  I really appreciate cs50 for doing all of this. Its just amazing opportunity.</p>
</body>

<footer class="py-3 my-4">
<ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="../about.html" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">About</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="../contact.html" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="../wiki.html" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Wiki</a></li>
</ul>
<p class="text-center text-muted">© 2022 Munkhsuld Baatarkhuu</p>
```

Comment: Bro paste your complete HTML so that it can be checked.

Comment: It looks as though you have gone straight from closing the footer to closing the html. Is there a body or container or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has more to do with the bootstrap CDN. Try writing an external style sheet for the project and then validate those styles by direct inputting them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33935456)

Answer (score -2):

it seems, that the problem was with the validator itself. other validators pretty much works fine.